# Bazel build and test after Tensorflow contribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, open-source, bazel

I have added functionality to `tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py` and corresponding unit tests in `tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_test.py`

I originally forked tensorflow from the `master` branch, made these changes on my local machine, rebased and commit.

Then I created and activated a virtualenv.

When running `bazel test //tensorflow/python...`, as recommended in the contribution guide I am recieving:

```
ERROR: /Users/isaacsultan/Code/tensorflow/third_party/python_runtime/BUILD:5:1: no such package '@local_config_python//': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/isaacsultan/Code/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 308
        _create_local_python_repository(repository_ctx)
    File "/Users/isaacsultan/Code/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 270, in _create_local_python_repository
        _check_python_lib(repository_ctx, python_lib)
    File "/Users/isaacsultan/Code/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 213, in _check_python_lib
        _fail(("Invalid python library path: %...))
    File "/Users/isaacsultan/Code/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 28, in _fail
        fail(("%sPython Configuration Error:%...)))
Python Configuration Error: Invalid python library path: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
 and referenced by '//third_party/python_runtime:headers'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/python:control_flow_util' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.603s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (8 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (8 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/core ... (2 packages)
```

What could the source of my issue be please?

Since I am only changing the python functionality, there is no need to rebuild.

EDIT: After re-running `./configure`:

```
(tensorflow) Isaacs-MacBook:tensorflow isaacsultan$ bazel clean --expunge
INFO: Starting clean.
(tensorflow) Isaacs-MacBook:tensorflow isaacsultan$ bazel test //tensorflow/python/...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
........................
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_isaacsultan/0e2667ab20883652d759a6a805575b2d/external/local_config_cc/BUILD:50:5: in apple_cc_toolchain rule @local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_x86_64: Xcode version must be specified to use an Apple CROSSTOOL. If your Xcode version has changed recently, try: "bazel clean --expunge" to re-run Xcode configuration
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/python/eager:core' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_x86_64' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 15.184s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (93 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (93 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/core ... (2 packages)
```

EDIT 2:

After running `bazel clean --expunge` then `./configure`:

```
Isaacs-MacBook:Tensorflow isaacsultan$ bazel test //tensorflow/python/...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
...................
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_isaacsultan/0e2667ab20883652d759a6a805575b2d/external/local_config_cc/BUILD:50:5: in apple_cc_toolchain rule @local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_x86_64: Xcode version must be specified to use an Apple CROSSTOOL. If your Xcode version has changed recently, try: "bazel clean --expunge" to re-run Xcode configuration
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/python:pywrap_tensorflow_import_lib_file' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '@local_config_cc//:cc-compiler-darwin_x86_64' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 14.969s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (88 packages loaded)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (88 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/core ... (5 packages)
```

EDIT 3:

After following these steps:
[Xcode version must be specified to use an Apple CROSSTOOL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276830/xcode-version-must-be-specified-to-use-an-apple-crosstool)

```
4 warnings generated.
ERROR: /Users/isaacsultan/Code/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:576:1: Executing genrule //tensorflow:tensorflow_python_api_gen failed (Exit 1)
/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_isaacsultan/0e2667ab20883652d759a6a805575b2d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/api/generator/create_python_api.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools.api.generator import doc_srcs
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_isaacsultan/0e2667ab20883652d759a6a805575b2d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_isaacsultan/0e2667ab20883652d759a6a805575b2d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
  File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_isaacsultan/0e2667ab20883652d759a6a805575b2d/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/create_tensorflow.python_api.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import keras_applications
ImportError: No module named keras_applications
INFO: Elapsed time: 57510.356s, Critical Path: 492.10s
INFO: 6867 processes: 6867 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Does this still happen with HEAD tf?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you forgot to run `./configure` before building?

Comment: Hello, yes I have run `./configure' before, but I tried again. I am now failing with a new output, see above please.

Comment: Hmm, looks like some bazel settings were left over before a system upgrade. Could you try `bazel clean --expunge`, then rerun configure, then finally retry testing?

Comment: Tried with no luck (see above)!

Comment: Maybe the commands here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45276830/xcode-version-must-be-specified-to-use-an-apple-crosstool

Comment: Thank you, after following those steps it now begins building. However, there is still a build error occurring. I'm trying this out: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21518